# Как заменить datasource в runtime?

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection

**Кратко:**
Пароль и юзер для доступа к БД меняются через равные промежутки времени. Как обновить пароль в runtime?

**Подробно:**
В приложении для подключения к БД postgres использую spring boot data jpa. Данные для подключения (username, password) хранятся на vault и меняются через равные промежутки времени, остальное хранится в properties. Соответственно, для создания подключения к БД я использую переопределенный бин datacource.

Вот он:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@PropertySource("classpath:bd.properties")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Value("${postgres.driver}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${postgres.url}")
    private String dataBaseUrl;
    private VaultUtil util;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserBase(VaultUtil util) {
        this.util = util;
        this.util.initParamForDataBase();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(dataBaseUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(util.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(util.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Как видно из этого кода, часть свойств получается из класса VaultUtil, который делает запрос на vault, в ответ получает json, читает оттуда username, password и сохраняет в переменные при вызове метода initParamForDataBase();

Вот код класса VaultUtil:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:bd.properties")
@Component
@Data
@Slf4j
public class VaultUtil {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String jsonProp;

    @Value("${vault.token}")
    private String vaultToken;

    @Value("${vault.url}")
    private String vaultUrl;

    @Value("${vault.x}")
    private String headName;


    private String getJsonFromVault() {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(vaultUrl);
        get.addHeader(headName, vaultToken);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.warn("IN getJsonFromVault() - HttpResponse didn't get");
        return null;
    }

    public void initParamForDataBase() {
        jsonProp = getJsonFromVault();
        try {
            this.username = mapper.readTree(jsonProp).get("data").get("username").asText();
            this.password = mapper.readTree(jsonProp).get("data").get("password").asText();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.warn("username and password didn't got: {} ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Приложение запускается и работает до смены пароля на vault, а затем при попытке подключения бросает `exception`:

```
2020-04-17 22:54:46.075  WARN 3832 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
2020-04-17 22:54:46.076 ERROR 3832 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "*****"
2020-04-17 22:54:46.081 ERROR 3832 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "*****"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:184) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.test.service.TestService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd8fd35f.getAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.test.controller.TestController.showAll(TestController.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Есть идеи как решить смену пароля в runtime? 
Замечания по коду также приветствую, так как я новичок и знаю что тут есть много спагетти.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать проект спринга [Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) целиком, либо взять оттуда только аннотацию **@RefreshScope**.

Пометив этой аннотацией ваш класс конфигураций, а также непосредственно бин датасорса, вы сможете на лету обновлять датасорс:

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@PropertySource("classpath:bd.properties")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Value("${postgres.driver}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${postgres.url}")
    private String dataBaseUrl;
    private VaultUtil util;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserBase(VaultUtil util) {
        this.util = util;
        this.util.initParamForDataBase();
    }

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(dataBaseUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(util.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(util.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Эта реализация будет прекрасно работать в случае, если у вас где-то настроен сервер конфигураций, который сообщает всем остальным модулям об изменении настроек.

Но в вашем случае понадобится принудительно сообщать приложению о том, что конфигурация изменилась.

Насколько я понял, то в вашем случае данные хранятся в базе данных и вы можете написать job, который будет ходить в базу данных и спрашивать логин и пароль и логику вы построите либо на последней дате изменения логин/пароля, либо на сравнении текущего с полученным из базы. Если пароли отличаются, то можно вызвать endpoint актуатора для обновления конфигураций (refresh()).

По умолчанию эндпоинт с версии спринг бута 2.0.1 выключен и вам необходимо будет его включить в конфигурации приложения добавив строчку в application.properties:

```
//включит вообще все эндпоинты актуатора, для включения только refresh - добавить refresh вместо *
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```